# What determines when grenade pickups respawn in ME3 multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

About 30 minutes ago, I decided to try out frag grenades rather than concussive shot in multiplayer. (About 29 minutes ago was when I started kicking myself for not trying out grenades sooner).

I noticed that you can refill your thermal clips pretty much anytime - the ammo crates restock themselves faster than an Ubercharged dispenser. Grenades, on the other hand, aren't always there for the taking; usually, I have to go kill some dudes first.

**What determines when grenade pickups respawn? Time, kills, waves, or something else entirely?**

Comment: glad you've discovered grenades, they are totally awesome.  From playing around, cluster grenades are the best, followed by the sticky, inferno, and frag grenades, with lift grenades being the worst (imo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The grenade spawns are time based, they're just on a different timer than the ammo respawn.
You can quickly see if there are grenades available in a stash as they have their own distinct graphic.

Also, there are different amounts of grenades per stash depending on the map and difficulty.  For example, Firebase Ghost has 2 grenades per ammo stash, on bronze you'll get 2 grenades from each for 4 total.  On silver and gold, you'll get 1 from each for a total of 2:

[image]

Comment: One thing I've been curious about that might fall under the umbrella of this question... if a different soldier gets to the grenade box ahead of me, will he take them all, or do we have totally different boxes?

Comment: he will take them all, ammo stashes are shared for the party.  When I'm spamming with my falcon assault rifle, I can easily use up every bit of ammo and grenades from a single stash.  You can visually see if the grenade is there in the stash, there is a small grenade graphic in there if its available.  I'll put up some screen shots when I get home.

Answer (score 2):

Alright as Yx said grenade resupplies are time based. Also keep in mind that each ammo dump has their own seperate supply of grenades. Grenade resupplies are different depending on the difficulty:

- Bronze = 2
- Silver = 1
- Gold = 1 (more time between grenades i noticed)

Ultimately you will find yourself going from one ammo dump to the next to keep your grenades full restocked, specially if your like me and have a capacity of 3 grenades. If someone else grabs the grenades of a particular ammo dump that you are racing towards and he grabs all of them, you will not be able to get grenades from there till the respawn again.

Comment: I distinctly remember picking up 3 grenades per stash from one of the maps on bronze, though I don't remember which one, or maybe I hit the grenade reset timer just right or something...

Comment: i promise its only 2 c:

Comment: hmm...  I'll have to take a look later when I get home since I definitely remember being pleasantly surprised when my grenade count went from 0 to 3

Comment: I have definitely gone from 0 to 3 grenades in a single pickup before. Maybe some crazy circumstances have to occur (like you picked up 1 of 2 earlier, then came back after a reset or something), but I know it can happen.

Comment: @Sterno some maps definitely have 2 grenades per stash, see my updated answer.

Comment: @yx. That would make sense!